# Bot runs but does not read or accept any command given by the user

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio, youtube-dl

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import youtube_dl

TOKEN = "removed"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

voice_client ={}

yt_dl_opts = {'format' : 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)

ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("{0.user} is online!".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("\play"):
        try:
            url = message.content.split()[1]

            voice_client = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
            voice_client[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executer(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))  #to get data from url 

            song = data['url']
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options, executable="C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")

            voice_client.play(player)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

the bot runs and become online but never accepts or read a command on the discord though i have given all rights.Please help me out as soon as possible.This is a music bot and i have already installed all the modules needed in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include message intents and message content intents to allow your bot to read the messages.
I tested it like this and it worked.

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import youtube_dl

TOKEN = "TOKEN_HERE"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents, messages = True, message_content = True)

voice_client ={}

yt_dl_opts = {'format' : 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)

ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("{0.user} is online!".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("\play"):
        try:
            url = message.content.split()[1]

            voice_client = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
            voice_client[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client
        
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executer(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))  #to get data from url 
    
            song = data['url']
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options, executable="C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
    
            voice_client.play(player)
    
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
    
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```